# video call using amazon-chime-web-sdk on firefox slowing down the mac-book

Tags: reactjs, firefox, freeze, aws-chime-sdk

I have written an application in react using amazon-chime-web-sdk. I do not render DOM anywhere in my code, the video call functionality is working fine in chrome but when I open the application in firefox 68.8.0esr (64-bit) on macbook, the other person's video is coming with  delay of approx 5 mins and that too very very slow frame rate. This somehow impact the CPU usage of the macbook and my macbook hangs a lot.

Did anyone encounter the same issue? What were the steps taken to prevent the same?